# Is there a wireless adapter for Canon 5D Mark II that will allow me to use the "EOS Remote app for iOS/Android"?

Tags: canon, canon-5d-mark-ii, wireless, canon-6d

The new Canon 6D has a built-in wi-fi that enables photographers to use the [EOS Remote app for iOS/Android.](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/EOS_app)

Is the 6D the only camera that can utilize this app? If not, what is the recommended wireless adapter to use with the 5D Mark II that will work with this app?

If this is possible I would be very interested in hands-on experience, especially in using the live-view.

Comment: Jakub - Just buy the 6D! Or else my Minnesota/Lake Superior shots are going to blow yours away come December!

Comment: LOL! That's the plan but I am so cheap. I do need a full frame companion for my 17-40 L but what if in December the mark II is 1199? If so, it will be a difficult decision. Right now I am leaning towards the 6D but I am not pre-ordering until I see the reviews.  Not to mention that at home my hobby is quite low on the priorities order.  (Wife, 3 kids, kids sports & hobbies, house repairs, many other items, photo equipment)

Comment: I pre-ordered the 6D w/24-105 on Amazon. I also just picked up the 17-40 a few weeks ago. If the 6D doesn't turn out to be what the doctor ordered, I figure I can always return it to Amazon and just pay the return shipping. I'll let you know how it is!

Comment: Sounds good! I am sure I will also want the 24-105 for the FF for an everyday walk about lens. And then the 14mm prime. Or the other way around. I think I have an addiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Canon make a wifi grip for the 5D Mark II called the [WFT-E4 II A](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/consumer_cameras_wft/wireless_file_transmitter_wft_e4_ii_a), which advertises **EOS Utility-based control of cameras over a network**. This provides similar functionality with PC/Mac based Canon EOS Utility software. There are similar grips available for the Canon 1D range (1DmkIII onwards), 5DmkIII and 7D.

However the wording on the page you linked (and [other similar Canon material](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_SLR/eos_remote.aspx)) states, under "**Compatible EOS Camera**", that "**The Canon EOS Remote app requires the use of a Canon EOS camera with built-in WiFi®**"<sup>1</sup>. And then lists only the Canon 6D.

The language is pretty specific to the 6D and having integrated wifi, however given the app also hasn't been released yet (expected December 2012), so I'd guess not, but it *might*<sup>2</sup> be a case of:

- A temporary marketing tool to drive interest in / focus on the brand new Canon 6D (it may well just work on any wifi-enabled EOS Utility-compatible camera, but for now they want to hype up the 6D).
- A permanent marketing tool to drive sales of new cameras, by artificially limiting compatibility to the 6D and future models only (in which case they *might* also release updated camera grips for current models, but that'll be the 5DmkIII, not the mkII).
- A technical upgrade to the network-based control protocol, without backwards compatibility. Perhaps they've had to update the protocol to support new features/functionality since network control was first introduced on the older wifi-grip-enabled cameras, and for some reason backwards compatibility isn't possible/worthwhile.

You probably won't get an answer until December.

---

<sup>1. Not sure if the ® indicates some specific name of a Canon feature you need to look for in specs?

2. **Warning:** Pure spectulation!</sup>

Comment: The name WiFi is a registered trademark of the WiFi Alliance, and you can't claim WiFi capability (which includes more than just the ability to operate over 802.11a,b,g or n wireless networks) without using their registered trademark.

Answer (score 0):

The *Connection Guide* that's part of the *EOS Remote* iOS app explicitly says:

> This app is compatible with the following camera models:
>
> EOS 6D (Wi-Fi)

No other models are listed, so one should probably assume that the current version won't work with the WiFi adapter.